I'm getting a "AttributeError: "Context" object has no attribute response" error when I'm running my code, any other way to get it running?
So I'm creating a simple discord modal using discord.py. But whenever I run my code I get an attributeError saying that the 'context' object doesn't have a response attribute. I know this is true, but I need to pass an interaction through the function to send a modal.
Others have suggested adding "await interaction.interaction.response.defer(ephemeral = True)" to my code, but that doesn't seem to work either. I'm wondering if there's a different way to get this working. I'm perplexed about modals. Please tell me if there's a different way they work.
Here's my code:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import ui


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?",intents=intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@client.command()
async def check(ctx):
    await ctx.send("What's up chat")

@client.command()
async def banana(ctx):
    await ctx.send("banana")

@client.command(name="modaltest")
async def modaltest(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    class MyModal(ui.Modal,title="Whatsup"):
        answer=discord.ui.TextInput(label="(LABEL_",style=discord.TextStyle.short, placeholder="Yes",default="Yes/No",required=True)
        async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message("It's time")
    await interaction.interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
    await interaction.response.send_modal(MyModal())




client.run('TOKEN')

And here's the output:
[2024-04-06 19:57:56] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 81799a7cbd347820290acba7203ba543).
We have logged in as Test bot#2666
[2024-04-06 19:58:07] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command modaltest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abhyu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abhyu\Desktop\python\main2.py", line 33, in modaltest
    await interaction.interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'response'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abhyu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\abhyu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\abhyu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'response'

If anyone has a way to actually function modals, or if there's an issue with my code, please do tell me!
(Oh and side question, how do you get the input submitted by the user from modals)

First of all, I don't know if it is a real token in your last line but never ever share it online as it can be used to control you bot. I suggest you to reset your token instantly as all servers with the Bot could be harmed if you do not.
Now onto the Error:
In Line 33 you wrote
await interaction.interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)

but it has to be
await interaction.response.defer()

In addition, after you have done the defer you need the following somewhere as if you do not, it will say "Interaction Failed":
await interaction.response.followup()

Also in the following this is my working Modal but the class isn't in the Command itself:
class Modal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(label="Short Input"))
        self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(label="Long Input", style=discord.TextStyle.long))

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        embed1=discord.Embed(title="Modal Results", description=f'|- **Short Input:** ```{self.children[0].value}``` |- **Long Input:** ```{self.children[1].value}```', color=discord.Colour.purple())
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed1, ephemeral=True)

In this case you get the Inputs with
{self.children[0].value}

and
{self.children[1].value}

Which can be used in a f-String seen in the embed which is send on_submit.
I hope I could help! If any other problems come along or the provided code does not work don't hesitate to contact me or maybe look into this Guide which I learned everything regarding this topic:
https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/ui-components/modal-dialogs

I didn't notice that when I first posted the question, thanks for telling me! That token is now no longer valid thankfully. I won't be making that mistake again.
